# Cross-browser dynamic setting of a CSS property

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

I have a function that gets many pieces of data and sets a CSS property for a defined element.

Here is the code:

```
function setStyle(element,property,target){
     element.style[property] = target;
}

var EL = document.getElementById("id");
setStyle(EL,"width","50px");
```

It works well in most browsers but not for IE6–IE9.

I've found `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle` and `element.currentStyle[type]`, but these methods get style and I can't use them to set.

Is there any way to do that for old IEs?

**i don't want to use jQuery or any other JS library**, thanks.

Comment: I've found http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ to be a helpful reference in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

The default way would be `element.style.property = "value"`, like:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.width = "50px";
```

There's no reason why it shouldn't work. But, as an alternative, consider setting the css style in a class, and adding it to the element by the `className` property.. It is widely supported:

css:

```
.myClass { width: 50px; }
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("id").className = "myClass";
```

**EDIT**

Yet another way around, that works in IE8+ (If you don't really need anything lower) would be setting the actual `style` atribute to the DOM element, so you can get the property as a parameter:

http://jsfiddle.net/ppf5qcvo/

```
function setStyle(element,property,target){
    element.setAttribute("style", property + ":" + target);
}
var el = document.getElementById("test");
setStyle(el, "color", "red");
```

Comment: i'm using it in a function , and I'm going to define property which should be changed in the function arguments , So i can't use `element.style.property = "value"`

Comment: **for edit**                                                          thanks,but I really need it to be supported on IE6

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using jQuery?  It handles all the cross browser issues for you.  You could accomplish the same thing with the following statement:

```
$('#id').width('50px');
```

Comment: `$('#id').css('width','50px')` to be precise.

Comment: sorry!i've forgot to say that i don't want to use jQuery or any other js library (edited)

Comment: Also, if you want to set other styles using jQuery, [refer here](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/style-properties/).